# Github.com's Markdown has stopped showing images inline

Tags: github, markdown, self-signed, ca

I noticed today that Github.com has stopped rendering images inline using paths relative to the repository's root —e.g.:

```
![Foo](/pics/foo.png "Some Foo")
```

I've tried adding `?raw=true` like so, but to no avail.

```
![Foo](/pics/foo.png?raw=true "Some Foo")
```

I've not been able to figure out why.

Also, I'm not sure this is related but I also noticed that now when I try to look at a file using the <kbd>Raw</kbd> button in Github.com's screen, Firefox throws an error `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` and Chrome throws `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. This never happened before.

I've not changed anything in my repositories or in my local workstation. I also see this issue from my phone. Something has definitely changed on Github.com's side.

Does anyone know if this is a temporary glitch or if it's a permanent change in Github.com's Markdown support and I should be doing something to my repo's to get images displayed again?

Comment: I just checked one of my repos and do not see the behavior described (inline images are working fine). I would guess the issue is related to the invalid certificate. Presumably, somewhere along the way an expired certificate for the site has been cached and that is causing the problem. The issue will most likely be resolved in time when a cache resets. Or you may need to clear your cache it it is local. Does the error only occur on one machine, from one location, or from anywhere?

Comment: Hi @Waylan. I had already checked the local cache and I was able to see this problem from two different laptops and from my phone over 4G. So it's not that. Now, don't you think if there were an expired cert somewhere along the way, then the error would be `SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE` on FF and `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on Chrome?